# sonarlint.exe is not a valid win32 application

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarlint

I am trying to analyse a c# project using sonarqube, but I keep on getting an error saying that sonarlint is not a valid win32 application, what is the reason for this?

```
[15:51:01]: [Step 1/3] 15:51:01.807 INFO  - Sensor FileHashSensor...
[15:51:01]: [Step 1/3] 15:51:01.838 INFO  - Sensor FileHashSensor done: 31 ms
[15:51:01]: [Step 1/3] 15:51:01.838 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor@375465a1...
[15:51:02]: [Step 1/3] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[15:51:02]: [Step 1/3] INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
[15:51:02]: [Step 1/3] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[15:51:02]: [Step 1/3] Total time: 26.359s
[15:51:02]: [Step 1/3] Final Memory: 53M/1397M
[15:51:02]: [Step 1/3] ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
[15:51:02]: [Step 1/3] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[15:51:02]: [Step 1/3] ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
[15:51:02]: [Step 1/3] ERROR: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "X:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxxx\.\.sonar\SonarLint.Runner\SonarLint.Runner.exe": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
[15:51:02]: [Step 1/3] ERROR: Caused by: Cannot run program "X:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\.\.sonar\SonarLint.Runner\SonarLint.Runner.exe": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
[15:51:02]: [Step 1/3] ERROR: Caused by: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Check if that file exists, and check if it can be run from command line. It may be case that this is 64 bit app and you have 32 bit system, or that it requires .NET framework that is not installed on the system.

Comment: the file exists and i get the same error when running from command line, i have a 64 bit system.

Comment: Did you run `SonarLint.Runner.exe` from command line or main script?

Comment: what is your OS? Windows XP isn't supported anymore by the .NET Framework 4.5.2 which is required by the C# plugin: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642

Answer (score 0):

Use a version of c# plugin not dependant/utilise sonarlint, I used 3.3, problem is that it is an older version, so not up to date with the latest rules.

Comment: this is a workaround, not a solution that should be recommended

Answer (score 0):

The SonarQube C# Plugin requires the .NET Framework version 4.6 to be installed. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww(v=vs.110).aspx, the .NET Framework no longer supports Windows Server 2003 since version 4.5.

I recommend that you upgrade your server's operating system and use the latest SonarQube C# Plugin, instead of getting stuck with old unsupported software.